# Input 2 names and output the average age

Tags: java

*This is for personal knowledge of how this works, is not for school*

Program requirements - Enter 2 Names. Have the program find the assigned values with the names and print the average between the two people.

I an not sure how to get the Scanner to take the input and go to the class to make it start processing. For example, in the main method if I `sysout print a`, it should display the string inside the method `getName`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainFallApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    rainfall a = new rainfall();
    rainfall b = new rainfall();

    System.out.println(a);

//      System.out.print("Please enter month one: ");
//      Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//      rain1 = aRain;
//      System.out.print("Please enter month two: ");
//      Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//      
//      int average = (rain1 + rain2) / 2;
//      System.out.println("The average rainfall for " + var + 
                            "and " + var2 +"is: "    + average);
}

}

class rainfall {
String rainamt;
String Rain_Amount;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String rainMonth = input.nextLine();

String rainAmount(String rainMonth) {
    Rain_Amount = getName(rainMonth);
    return Rain_Amount;
}

private String getName(String rainMonth) {

    if (rainMonth.equals("Jan")) {
        rainamt = "3.3";
    }
    else if (rainMonth.equals("Feb")) {
        rainamt = "2.2";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not a valid month name");
    }
    return rainamt;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to say `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` once. Then you can use the scanner's `nextLine()` method to input data. It returns a string, so be sure to store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I completed my program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainFallApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the first month: ");
    String aMonth = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter the second month: ");
    String bMonth = input.nextLine();


    rainfall aRainfall = new rainfall();
    String aName = aRainfall.rainAmount(aMonth);
    Double aAmount = Double.parseDouble(aName);

    rainfall bRainfall = new rainfall();
    String bName = bRainfall.rainAmount(bMonth);
    Double bAmount = Double.parseDouble(bName);

    double Avg = (aAmount + bAmount) / 2;

    System.out.println("\nIn the month of " + aMonth + " it had " 
+ aAmount + " inches        of rain.");
    System.out.println("In the month of " + bMonth + " it had "
+ bAmount + " inches of rain.");
    System.out.println("The average rainfall between the two months is: " + Avg);

}

}

class rainfall {
    private String Rain_Amount;

    String rainAmount(String rainMonth) {
        Rain_Amount = getAmount(rainMonth);
        return Rain_Amount;
}

private String getAmount(String rainMonth) {

    if (rainMonth.equals("Jan")) {
        Rain_Amount = "3.3";

    }
    else if (rainMonth.equals("Feb")) {
        Rain_Amount = "2.3";
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not a valid month name");
    }
    return Rain_Amount;
}
}
```